# maximum size of array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

So I am working on a problem where I am dealing with very large amounts of data and I have come across a limitation I do not fully understand. I need to store sets of 6 integer values and associate each with an index. The approach I chose was to initially create my own type and then create a List(of Type). That failed with an 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range" error. Fine, I presumed that this was due to the Type I defined and perhaps the way the List/Collection was storing the data. I was expecting to make use of the full Integer.MaxValue number of indices in an array, as given in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_ArraySize but that seems to not apply (why?). I then proceeded to re-write the functions and ended up with an array of type Tuple(int,int,int,int,int,int). But again, I run into the same situation. Same for arrays of a type that has an array as its variable. I tried out several ways to see what the maximum size of the array could be and ended up with a maximum size of around 48E6 indices. The problem is that I need more than 10x that to store the data I have...
The only way I found to make this (sort of) work is to use a List(of List(of Integer())) and then add a new item to the top level list after every 40M indices or so. Nasty solution and not efficient, but it showed that it could be made to work...
Background: VS2010, .NET 4.0, Win7 x64, 32GB Ram.

Any ideas of how I would best store 6 integer values in either a collection or array (I need to be able to access them by index) for more than about 500 million combinations (ideally up to the 2.1B combinations)?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the EXACT code you used because it's something specific to what you're doing.  I just tried to create an array of the maximum size and got an `OutOfMemoryException`.  In your case, my guess is that your `List(Of T)` keeps doubling the size of its internal array, which is how a list grows, until the new size would be greater than `Integer.MaxValue`.

Comment: The 'OutOfMemoryException' is due to insufficient Memory being available on your system (Dim _array(integer.maxvalue) as Integer would presumably require the full 2GB of RAM which may not be free). The issue here is an error of type 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range' when the array size is below integer.maxValue.

Comment: I realise why I saw an `OutOfMemoryException`. I pointed that out because I was wondering why you didn't see the same thing if there was indeed an attempt to create an array of that size. You say that your array size is below `Integer.MaxValue` but how do you know? You were using a `List(Of T)` so how do you know what size the internal array was? Even if you know, how do we know? I SPECIFICALLY asked you to post your code and you have not. I wouldn't asked if it wasn't important. If you want an answer then stop making it hard for us. Provide information when it's requested.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I'm sorry didn't mean to confuse... I used two approaches:
Dim _a(500000000) as Tuple(of integer,integer,integer,integer,intger,integer) 
which throws and error as soon as I call it (which is why I wrap it in a Try...Catch...End Try) 
and also a code like this:
Dim i as integer
Dim someList as List(of Tuple (of Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
Try
 For i=0 to integer.MaxValue-1
  someList.add(new Tuple(of Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)(1,2,3,4,5,6))
 Next
Catch 
 MsgBox("Error at " & i.tostring & " Ex: " & ex.message)
End Try

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually quite simple (thanks coffee). Reading through the documentation in the link above, this should not be the problem, but... the maximum size of the array is no longer Int.MaxValue once the type isn't an integer (or so it would seem, though none of the documentation indicates this). The way around this is simply to go from something like this:

```
Dim _Array(Array_Size) as Tuple(of Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)
```

to

```
Dim _Array1(Array_Size) as Integer
Dim _Array2(Array_Size) as Integer
Dim _Array3(Array_Size) as Integer
Dim _Array4(Array_Size) as Integer
Dim _Array5(Array_Size) as Integer
```

This allows each array the maximum size (or at least the size I need which is close enough to the max size). The only thing is that I then need to expand the rest of the code accordingly.
I am a bit surprised about this, considering that the MSDN states that 'The length of every dimension of an array is limited to the maximum value of the Integer data type' when it looks like it should actually read that 'The Total length [...] is limited to the maximum value'. That would explain that I receive an error (of the original statement) at a size that accounts for the additional 6 integer values plus some for accounting.